# No (valid) input data found! in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am loading XML data using Pig. When I issue an ILLUSTRATE command I get an error. Here is what I am doing.

```
REGISTER piggybank-0.15.0.jar
xml = LOAD '/xml/data/path' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('doc') as (x:chararray);
ILLUSTRATE xml;
```

Here is the **ERROR**

`....
.....
2018-03-20 19:56:52,265 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapOnly$Map - Aliases being processed per job phase (AliasName[line,offset]): M: xml[6,6] C:  R:
2018-03-20 19:56:52,266 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.pen.AugmentBaseDataVisitor - No (valid) input data found!
java.lang.RuntimeException: No (valid) input data found!
        at org.apache.pig.pen.AugmentBaseDataVisitor.visit(AugmentBaseDataVisitor.java:585)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.accept(LOLoad.java:230)
        at org.apache.pig.pen.util.PreOrderDepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(PreOrderDepthFirstWalker.java:82)
        at org.apache.pig.pen.util.PreOrderDepthFirstWalker.walk(PreOrderDepthFirstWalker.java:66)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)
        at org.apache.pig.pen.ExampleGenerator.getExamples(ExampleGenerator.java:180)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.getExamples(PigServer.java:1250)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processIllustrate(GruntParser.java:831)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.Illustrate(PigScriptParser.java:802)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:381)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:547)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
2018-03-20 19:56:52,283 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. Exception`

I have verified the path for the data and for sure the data does exist. To confirm this I have loaded the data using PigStorage instead of XMLLoader and I could see the ILLUSTRATE command to be working and also dumping `xml` had some data in the output. It's the XMLLoader that is causing the problem here, I guess. Not sure about the exact issue.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me too when I try an ILLUSTRATE command over a table load, try performing another function and ILLUSTRATE that.